# What is the maximum party size and the corresponding monster buffs?

Tags: diablo-iii

What is the maximum party size (if there is one) in *Diablo 3*?

Additionally, how much of a buff do monsters get when adding party members?

> "A new ally has joined, but the minions of Hell grow stronger."

Comment: Albort, please limit yourself to one question per... question. No one is hurt by additional questions on the site.

Comment: @authenticgeek While there are plenty of cases in which multiple part questions should be split, I don't think this qualifies. Maximum party size and monster buffs per party member are two bits of related info which anyone looking for one will most likely want to know the other. In fact, I think this question would be best modified to be a more general "What are the effects of partying in D3?" Some of the other pieces of info in Sean's answer and it's comments are also closely related to the question asked, but won't be easily found using search as the question is too limited in scope.

Comment: gah, I can't add a bounty to this question from work for some reason, if the answer isn't updated later I'll post one

Comment: @z- I posted the bounty.

Comment: @DiabloMonkey *tips hat*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of the 1.05 patch on 10/16/2012, monsters gain a 70% HP increase for each additional character.  So a 4-person Inferno party would face monsters with 210% more health than a solo character.  (Prior to 1.04, the % increase per character was higher on higher difficulty levels).

Patch 1.08 reduces the HP-buff to 50% per player, resulting in a maximum of 150% more health.

This increase is applied AFTER any increase for monster power level.  So at Inferno MP1 with one player, monsters have 150% hit points.  With four players at MP1, they would have (150 * 3.1) = 465% hit points.

**Update**: There used to be a bonus to damage on higher difficulty levels, but it was removed in a [hotfix](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6214196) on June 8, 2012.

Comment: [This site](http://www.clicktoloot.com/p/combat.html#multiplayer%20scaling) backs up your information :-)

Comment: @Brysonic Yah, but everyone is just repeating info from the same source, I don't know if anyone has actually done SCIENCE to confirm it yet.

Comment: @Arperum (since you were last edit) and also bwarner; is the information in this answer still valid, or have there been changes with 2.0?  Either way, can you edit the answer to indicate either that the information is applicable to 2.0 or what the new values are?

Comment: @Doc it needs an update anyway since it doesn't mention the new difficulty system. i don't think the numbers changed, I don't remember seeing that in the patchnotes.

Comment: @bwarner Can you update this as of 2.0 or verify that it has not changed in RoS?

Comment: @Diablo I don't own RoS, so I may not be the best person to make the update.  Someone else can do it, or create their own answer if they would prefer.

Answer (score 12):

The maximum party size is **four people**.<sup>[1](http://www.destructoid.com/preview-diablo-iii-beta-207543.phtml) [2](http://www.diablowiki.net/Maximum_game_size)</sup> There is **no party experience split**.<sup>[3](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/3389260164#4)</sup>

For **each** additional party member, monster health scales: **+75% HP** in Normal, **+85% HP** in Nightmare, **+95% HP** in Hell, **+110% HP** in Inferno.<sup>[4](http://diablo.incgamers.com/forums/showthread.php?824597-Party-Size-and-Monster-HP&p=8232232&viewfull=1#post8232232) [5](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/40969-monster-hpdmg-increase-per-player-new-info/#entry862813)</sup> (The upcoming 1.0.4 patch changes this. Instead of scaling monster health buffs with difficulty, **all difficulties get a flat +75% HP increase** per each additional party member.<sup>[6](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6923456/104_Systems_Preview-8_10_2012)</sup>) There are **no other** party size buffs.

Comment: Is +HP the only difference?

Comment: That citation for the buff seems dubious as it says XP doesn't change; does it not split when multiple people are around and just give X to everyone in range?  People don't level appreciably slower in a group.

Comment: XP doesn't split ever, the same way that loot/gold drops are individual, not shared.

@bwarner: afaik, yes

Comment: -1 It would appear this information is partially incorrect (outdated?), since it lacks the information on how hell this differs based on difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the buff to monsters, as of 1.0.8 (currently in PTR):

> Monsters currently[1.0.7] gain 70% extra health per additional player in the game. This is being reduced from 70% to 50%. This means in a two-player game, monsters have 150% as much health as a single-player game. In a three-player game, they have 200% as much health. And in a four-player game, they have 250% as much health (compared to 310% on live).

[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/9382478/developer-journal-multiplayer-improvements-4-2-2013)