# Do I earn less experience or items if I have a follower?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Cathedral Level 3, I have the chance to either fight with or without the Templar. I thought the enemies would grow stronger relative to the size of my party, but typically this is announced by the game and there was no such message when I accepted him straight away.

Will I get experience and drops from his kills/last blows/etc.? Will I be getting less of it overall? perhaps more?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Only when you connect with a real-life player will the monsters get harder.

The in-game NPCs that you can recruit make no difference to the difficulty and you will continue to receIve the same experience and loot.

On another note, the loot differs from player to player, so you dont have to worry about people stealing it.

Comment: "You will also recieve slightly better loot and a little more experience."  There is no direct affect between having more players and experience or loot.  You only do better if you are killing faster as a group than you would solo (which is likely true).

Answer (score 47):

**Followers do not inherently affect monster HP/difficulty, experience (XP) share, or item/gold drops.** They're designed to make single-player easier, and there is no statistical *disadvantage* for using them. They ***contribute* 20% of their added Magic Find, Gold Find, and XP bonuses**.<sup>[1](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4142245733#1) [2](http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/218401-follower-gold-magic-find-equipment/) [3](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/magic-find-and-gold-find-now-shared-through-the-party) [4](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS456US456&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cache%3Aus.battle.net%2Fd3%2Fen%2Fforum%2Ftopic%2F4079626032%3Fpage%3D1%2313)</sup> And, [like *D2* hirelings](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/basics/experience.shtml), their kill XP counts as your XP.

Also remember that followers cannot be used with parties and that [*D3*'s party size **only** affects monster HP](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/63440/21177). There is no party XP, item, or gold split—everyone gets the same XP, and drops are private (so as to reduce infighting).

Comment: Followers **can** affect monsters drops. because you get 20% of their MF

Answer (score 7):

Everything stays the same.  He is only a Follower/Hireling who does not affect the game except by helping you and giving you his equipped item stats, e.g. magic find, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You don't get less experience, but you will lose any gold or magic find percentage.

Comment: You don't lose GF/MF when you have a follower at all. You can even gain GF/MF when you equip him with corresponding gear. That is true now and was also true in 2012.