# Disadvantages of taking follower with you

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I earn less experience or items if I have a follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63459/do-i-earn-less-experience-or-items-if-i-have-a-follower)

In Diablo 3, is there any penalty for taking follower (compared to playing alone)?

I'm aware monster's HP scales with the size of group (for every extra player monster gets +75% HP, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: This has already been covered by the linked question. If you feel this question is not a duplicate, please edit it to emphasize the difference, then flag it and ask for it to be reopened.

Comment: I believe that to answer your question you need to check at least 2 answers in that question. But I guess your answer is there.

Comment: @MichelAyres - It is, I found what I was looking for. Just, when using search option, I got lots of Skyrim related Q&A and I missed that (linked) question.

Comment: You can add tags into your search as well. take a look at our [search](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=)

Comment: @MichelAyres I didn't know that. Thank you!