# Is there a cost of using the follower?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I earn less experience or items if I have a follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63459/do-i-earn-less-experience-or-items-if-i-have-a-follower)

I always thought it was free, but then the other day one of them said he was here for the gold, and I started to wonder,

Does he take part of the gold? 
Do you take less experience with him fighting with you?

Comment: There is no cost for using a follower, see here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63459/do-i-earn-less-experience-or-items-if-i-have-a-follower, see the answer with most up-votes, it's better then the accepted answer.

Comment: Exact duplicate. See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65625/disadvantages-of-taking-follower-with-you was closed as duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63459/do-i-earn-less-experience-or-items-if-i-have-a-follower

Answer (score 0):

The follower just help you in combat. 
If the follower has any +GF, +MF, or +XP per kill items on him, you will get 20% of their worth. And he will take his own exp growing and helping you in different and more usefull ways.

The only "cost" is the equipment you have to buy [or not sell..] for him ^^

Comment: So you actually get less experience?

Comment: Talking 5 minutes ago with a friend he say me you will recieve slightly better loot and a little more experience!!!
I'm correcting the answer.

Comment: Please provide a source that the follower effects loot.  My understanding is he has no effect on how much gold drops or changes what items can drop beyond the +MF or +Gold on his gear.

Comment: [I read this here](http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/218401-follower-gold-magic-find-equipment/)