# Should I let the Templar join my party?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I earn less experience or items if I have a follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63459/do-i-earn-less-experience-or-items-if-i-have-a-follower)

In Act 1 of Diablo 3, I encounter a warrior who is later revealed to be a Templar. After I help him find his weapons, he wants to join my party. The only condition is that if I encounter the tomes of his order, I give them to him.

What are the benefits of letting the Templar join my party? Are their any drawbacks? Does having a follower increase minion difficulty like when you're playing with other people?

Answer (score 5):

It does not have any downsides. He doesn't take a cut of your XP, Gold, or anything else.

The templar (and the other followers you will meet) also have special abilities to aid you in battle. For example, the Templar can heal you.

Also, minion difficulty is not increased.