# +MF or +XP rings on followers

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I earn less experience or items if I have a follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63459/do-i-earn-less-experience-or-items-if-i-have-a-follower)

When giving my follower a ring with *+ Magic Find* or *+ Kill XP*, will I benefit from it, too?

I assume MF does affect me since a follower cannot loot anything but for XP I'm pretty unsure since followers *do* have their own XP bar.

Comment: Answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/63542/8350

Answer (score 3, accepted):

20% of your followers' +XP, magic find and gold find are added to your corresponding stat.

http://www.diablofans.com/blizz-tracker/topic/218401-follower-gold-magic-find-equipment/

Comment: Still trying to find out about XP... And found.