# Do more followers act the same as a multiplayer game?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I earn less experience or items if I have a follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63459/do-i-earn-less-experience-or-items-if-i-have-a-follower)

In Diablo 3, when you are playing with more people online, the monsters are harder to kill. Does the same logic follow during single player action?

I am currently using the Witch Doctor class, I have a templar following me, 3 rabid dogs out helping during battle and sometimes get a quest where someone else joins me for a little while.

Answer (score 0):

No, the AI followers do not make the game more difficult. Only other players. This is because the followers, even if well equipped, cannot provide the damage another player could.

Answer (score 0):

Only other players affect the monsters in a game. The followers do not count towards increasing their HP, stats, etc...

If you notice when someone joins your game, it states "The monsters of hell grow stronger." This does not happen when you recruit a follower.