# How is experience going to work in Multiplayer?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I ever get xp for my party member's kills?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63605/do-i-ever-get-xp-for-my-party-members-kills)
>   [Does party size affect chance of better loot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64047/does-party-size-affect-chance-of-better-loot)

I was looking around and I didn't find any good source that provides a good explanation (baby steps) on how is experience going to work in Diablo 3 multiplayer.

- The experience is individual like loot/gold?
- The members of the party receive extra experience per member in the party? (party bonus)
- Does monsters give more experience because you are playing in a party?

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the maximum party size and the corresponding monster buffs?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/63433/21177) and [Does party size affect chance of better loot?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/64047/21177)

Comment: @sean - That's about loot, not experience.  (I realize the answer to this is mentioned over there but it's good to have the separate question for search purposes, IMO)

Comment: If closed as a duplicate, search forwards the result

Comment: The only link that is similar to my question is [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/63644/12936) but is not clear enough for me, I add a comment there to get a better answer for me, the other links are relevant, but not duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

All members of the party earn full experience points for each monster killed - the number of players doesn't affect the experience for killing a monster.  (You do have to be within 1-2 screens of the kill to get credit, though)