# Does everyone in the party get the same item drop?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does party size affect chance of better loot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64047/does-party-size-affect-chance-of-better-loot)

When a monster is killed and an item is dropped in multiplayer, does everyone get the same item? Or does the item get randomized for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

It is randomized for everyone. The items are totaly dependant on your session. While you might get a rare from a monster the guy you play with might only get a regular item.

Answer (score 0):

The items that drop from monsters are **randomized for everyone** (like the D3 tutorial says, **"everyone gets their own loot"**, but depending on your own Magic Find / Gold Find, you may acquire better items ranging from Magic to even Legendaries.

However, if you don't want to farm and wait for a Rare or Legendary (Magic is pretty  common) to drop, or one that randoms you a good amount of stats, you could always visit the Auction House. Trading loot is one way to improve yourself as well.