# Does quest progress in co-op carry over to single player?

Tags: diablo-iii

For example, if my friend hosts a game and I join it and we go through the entirety of Act I, will I have to beat Act I all over again once I leave the co-op session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While in CO-OP.

- You gain achievements for co-op **and** for single.
- You quest log count for co-op and for single.

So you gain more achievements playing as a group than solo. You don't lose nothing. But remember [monsters get 75% more health for each player in the party](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/63440/122).

---

About the quest progress.

- You are starting ACT III quest 1
- Your friend is starting ACT III quest 4
- You jump in your friend game and finish ACT III with him

You'll be able to start all quest beyond 4 and the first quest in ACT III. But You'll need to complete the quests 1, 2 and 3 from ACT III.

Comment: Interestingly this absolutely did not work for me and another player the other day, we joined a mates campaign who was one mission behind us, we all completed act 1 and then when we finished for the night, logged in the next day, my campaign was back to where i was before i joined his game, and so was the other guy i joined the game with... bug?

Comment: @Ben You probably have to select new quest to start your campaign from that point (and effectively skip in zour campaign what you have playd in MultiPlayer)

Answer (score 4):

You won't have to redo the act. Every quest your character completes is completed both when playing with, and without, friends.