# Do dungeons, enemies or their abilities change depending on what class you're playing?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I'm a monk will I see different monster combinations and abilities compared to say a wizard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the enemies and dugeons will generate the same regardless of the class. There is always a sense of randomness in the way Diablo generates, but it is **not** based on class. This is one of the challeneges of Diablo. If they changed it based on your class the game would basically explode when you were playing co-op.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, dungeons, enemies (and their abilities) and even treasure does not depend on your class. Dialog lines and cutscenes do, though.

Answer (score 0):

No. The changes in the monsters occur when:

**You are in a party**

- Monsters get +75% HP for every additional party member.[¹](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/63440/12936)

**In a different difficulty level (Normal, Nightmare, Hell, Inferno)**

> These advanced enemies will have extra randomised abilities, including
>   area of effect attacks, more ranged skills and area denial abilities
>   designed to split up your team. On Hell and Inferno difficulties these
>   creatures will get up to four extra special abilities, turning them
>   into miniature bosses. Killing them will give you a chance to collect
>   some of the best loot in the game.
>
> Item drops improve with each difficulty mode, of course, but once you
>   reach Inferno mode, top level items are divided into increasingly
>   devastating tiers.

[Source](http://www.pcgamer.com/2011/10/22/diablo-3-70-of-items-appear-beyond-normal-difficulty/)

This two are the only changes with monsters.