# Diablo 3 Difficulty scaling per added player

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum party size and the corresponding monster buffs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63433/what-is-the-maximum-party-size-and-the-corresponding-monster-buffs)

What is the exact scaling when it comes to different number of players and is it the same in the higher difficulties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

This is out of the Diablo 3 Signature Series Guide.

**NOTE**: As of June 8th, monsters no longer receive a damage buff on higher difficulties.

Comment: So in Inferno you're better off going it alone...?

Comment: Not necessarily. Skill synergies and the presence of multiple (potential) tanks make things much easier.

Comment: Well in Inferno you need to get a good group, with good class distribution, that actually works together. In all other modes you are encouraged to play with others, no matter their class.