# How is the difficulty increased when other people join?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum party size and the corresponding monster buffs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63433/what-is-the-maximum-party-size-and-the-corresponding-monster-buffs)

So, as we know, difficulty is increased as soon as other char joins the party, but I've always wondered, is that difficulty related with the level of the player?

For ex, Im playing with my lvl 30 char, is the same if another player with level 40 joins, than if another player with the level 25 joins?

Comment: This is a dupe. Trying to find it. Stand by.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63433/what-is-the-maximum-party-size-and-the-corresponding-monster-buffs/67059#67059

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the player level is related for the same reasons the game difficulty doesn't change based on your level (Hell is hard for a 35 but easy for level 50+). The number of players is what determines the increase in difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Your enemies get 75% stronger per team member.

Comment: In "normal" yes. I's more in nightmare and they get also a +15% damage. I's even more in hell and inferno.

Comment: "Stronger" is vague and this varies by difficulty. Anyone reading this, please reference [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67059/5291) for the actual values.