# When does the health buff for enemies occur in coop games?

Tags: diablo-iii

When a player joins a coop game, enemies get a health buff.
(As detailed in [What is the maximum party size and the corresponding monster buffs?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63433/what-is-the-maximum-party-size-and-the-corresponding-monster-buffs))

But when does this buff apply?
Let's say I'm fighting a boss and he has 1000 total hp, and I downed it to 50% hp, so he has 500 hp left. If a new player suddently joins the game, the remaining 500 hp for the boss get immediately increased? or it stays the same for enemies already spawned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will immediately increase so as to remain at the exact same % of total hp.

Therefore, if you're in an inferno game and a friend joins while an enemy has 100k health left, it will immediately jump up to 210k health.

Comment: I am not sure that is correct for a boss. The reason is that while fighting a boss, no one else can enter the fight, so if the boss's HP jumps it'sss SOOO wrong. This might happen if you die, and fight the boss again.

Comment: @Saariko nope, it will immediately jump up or down depending on whether a team mate joins or leaves. That's why in hardcore boss fights, if one person dies they normally leave as soon as possible to make the fight easier on the other person.

Comment: I am not playing HC (not since I was butchered once in Old D2 at Level 30 by a WW barbarian :-)  so I can't comment on that.